# Get missed element of array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method which receives an array

```
public static int getMissed(int[] array) {...}
```

For example it will be {1,3,5,7,11}
As you can see 4d element is missed, it should be 9.

For example array's size is unknown and step is unknown, how can i find missed element? 
I have no idea. It was the question from my test task and i could not solve it.

Comment: please show your effort?

Comment: In this case we know it's 9. What other rules can be applied to elements?

Comment: Take up to 4 elements to find the step, then either iterate, or use binary search

Comment: I don't get why is *4d element* missing, and why it should be 9... Could you try to explain your problem some other way?

Comment: @sp00m Because each element is +2 of previous one..

Comment: sp00m i meant 4 index of array, and Maroun is rught

Comment: tod, i wrote, i have no idea

Comment: @user3673623 is my answer correct&good for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this just to give a solution. I'm sure there will be better answers.

```
public static int getMissed(int[] array) {

    int difference, difference_2;

    if (array.length < 3) // we need at least 3 elements 
        return -1; 

    difference   = array[1] - array[0];
    difference_2 = array[2] - array[1];

    if (difference == difference_2) {
        for (int i = 3; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] - array[i - 1] != difference) {
                return array[i] - difference;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (difference > difference_2)
            return array[1] - difference_2;
        else
            return array[2] - difference;
    }
    return -1;
}
```